# how to make boston city map in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, geojson

I am new to d3.geo. I don not have any ideo on how do I make boston city map using d3.js ? 
I want to show the simple outline map of Boston with it's neighborhood areas, so that further i can make a chloropleth map on the Boston map. From where should I get the Geojson data for Boston?

Comment: The project will get a lot easier when old-school Boston people show up to inform you that only a particular 3-block area can really be considered Boston - you'll just have to pick which one to display

Comment: You can get the lat/long polygons from my Boston reverse geolocation library: https://github.com/daveross/boston-neighborhood-reverse-geocoder/blob/master/src/boston_neighborhoods.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want?

[image]

Here is the code:
https://github.com/EcutDavid/D3In20Days/blob/master/scripts/day20.js

and you can implement chloropleth map for sure.